# tinyMCE on dynamically generated textarea doesn't get focus with mceFocus

Tags: tinymce, focus

after clicking on a div I am generating a textarea. After then I am loading tinyMCE on it. This works well but after loading the tinyMCE I want to set focus on it using "mceFocus". This isn't working. No focus set regardless which browser I try.

```
$.when(
            btn.parent().html('<textarea autocomplete="off" name="' + fld + '" id="' + fld + '" readonly></textarea>')
        ).done(function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, fld);
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, fld);
        });
```

Comment: FYI: I already also tried
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
    tinyMCE.get('fields_id').focus();
Nothing worked.

Comment: Just figured out that it doesn't work only at the first field. The next fields I am creating are taking focus as supposed.